# Cannot delete file 0 byte file from Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a bunch of 0 byte files in my buckets, possibly due to errors during upload. I've tried deleting the files both through the Google Storage GUI:

[image]
*(Returns success, but file re-appears on refresh)*

Using gsutil:

```
gsutil rm gs://bucket/myfile.xml # returns "Operation completed over 1 objects."
```

And by using the client library `v0.20.0-beta`:

```
val client: Storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService
client.delete(BlobId.of(bucketName, path)) // returns true the first time, then false
```

But nothing works ...

***NB:** I have not tried deleting the bucket itself, because it contains thousands of (mostly non-corrupted) files used by our application*

Comment: They still show up with `gsutil ls` after deleting them with `gsutil rm`?

Comment: Indeed it is. http://imgur.com/a/fvO4h

Comment: @jterrace now it all of a sudden works ... I have no changed a thing, simply tried to delete the 0 byte files, and now they're gone. Is GS this unreliable?